# Windows - keep audio playing on out of focus windows (games)

Tags: windows, audio

I've been running games in windowed mode (on another screen), but when the window loses focus, audio stops.
Is there a way to keep audio running even when window is out of focus? I'm using windows 10 (and playing Magic The Gathering Duels)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the windowed window of the game as being always on top with this free utility: "OnTopReplica"

Hope it helps.